# Black screen in Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: nvidia, uefi, 22.04, bios, secure-boot

I have an ASUS Prime b350m-a motherboard with BIOS version 6042, a Nvidia 710 video card and a ryzen 3 1300x processor.
I tried to install  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and everything is correct but when I turn off the PC and turn it back on, after a few minutes it freezes on a black screen.
I have to force it to shut down and from there turn it back on so that it starts normally.
I have the BIOS set as:

- CSM: UEFI and Legacy
- Boot/Secure boot: Other OS.

I would like to know if anyone has had the same problem, if it could be due to bios settings or if I have to modify the grub boot.
Regards.

Comment: Have you installed an nvidia graphics driver or are you using the free linux driver 'nouveau'?

Comment: The problem is not related to these BIOS settings.

Comment: @sudodus I have installed the NVIDIA driver recommended by ubuntu, the window system however appears to me as X11

Comment: @GenGL, What happens when you turn off the PC *wait 5 minutes* and turn it back on? In other words, could the problem be rebooting 'directly' or 'too early' because some electronic component is not fully reset or discharged?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> for some reason I changed the title of the original question and it totally missed the point of what I wanted to solve.

I originally asked if the bios configuration or version affects the performance of Ubuntu in some cases.

Researching separately I found that the updated bios versions on some motherboards are not optimized for Ubuntu, and the new ones only focus on Windows.

So if you want to update the bios of your computers you should think twice, whether you have a dual boot, only gnu-linux or derivatives, because there are many errors such as reboot or forced shutdowns and constant data corruption problems.

In my particular case you should only update the bios to version 5406 said this on the recommendation of the ASUSTEK team, then use another motherboard with an older bios version and has been working without problem.

Comment: In English please!

Comment: Lamentablemente no soy hablante del ingles, pero puedes usar el traductor de google :)
-----
Unfortunately I am not an English speaker, but you can use the google translator :)
----
@Pilot6 Your negative vote is unnecessary, a little more empathy with beginners please.

Comment: This site allows posts only in English. You can use a translator ;-) Otherwise the post will be deleted.

Comment: @Pilot6 Delete it if you want, I got an answer, if someone else needs it I'm sorry for them. :(

Comment: It takes 30 seconds to run a post through Google translate or similar, and thus is a trivial fix/change.  Note also that just because people say an issue is not related to something OR posting you need to use English does NOT mean it's unfriendly or abusive speech in comments so don't flag those as that.